# The domain cube is visible in render

Tags: fluid-simulation, render-layers, mantaflow

The domain is visible at 64 and 182 domain voxel res.

The cube object properties is set to wire view and they physics sim is baked. Compositing is set image->image.
[here](https://github.com/ZoomDomain/Flamethrower-demo-for-blender-metaflow/raw/main/Finished_flamethrower%20%20(8c).blend) is the file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What material have you got on your domain, would you please show the node setup in the _Shader Editor_?

Comment: it's the default fire+smoke material, I havent used the shader editor yet, i will change the shader there and see if it's running.

Comment: What you have on the domain is not the default fire+smoke material, it's a surface material which only shows on the surface of the mesh - which is a cube. The fire+smoke you see in viewport is not a material (you are not in Material Preview mode), it's the visualisation of the created fire and smoke volumetric data. Don't know what you mean by "shader macro", but I guess it was all greyed out because you had no material on the domain or it wasn't selected or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check the shader editor, set it to node view at the top, and change it to principled volume.

Comment: I would highly recommend you watch some tutorials on simulating fire + smoke and how to create smoke materials.